# In what sense are blurry images convolutions, and what are they convolved with?

Tags: optics, visible-light, geometric-optics

I've heard before that images which are out of focus can be described as the (clear) image convolved with some "blurriness function" which I assume depends on the lens and other optical arrangements. How can I prove this? How can I see this? What function, exactly, does the image get convolved with and why?

Answer (score 0):

Convolution can be interpreted as averaging around each point in the image. Therefore, each specific point in the out of focus image is transformed to a point that is a weighted average of surrounding points in a region surrounding the specific point in the focused image. This is what causes blurriness.

To "prove" this, you can try first to trace a few rays of an upright object passing through a lens, as we do in introductory geometric optic. When the image is focused, the rays emitted by each point of the object will arrive at the same distance from the axis of the lens for all rays that catch the lens. However, if you are out of focus, each point in the image is transformed into a small segment (in the 1D image), or in a small patch (in the case of a 2D image). Since each point of the object forms its own patch in the out of focus image, the patches from many points of the object will be superposed at each out of focus image location. If you formalize this, you will get to the convolution integral.